# Netbeans + GIT error when trying to clone a project "Algorithm negotiation fail"

Tags: git, netbeans

I have got a git repository.

I know it works because I have tested it by cloning the repository from a cygwin terminal:

```
git clone git@frojasg1.com:/home/git/proyectos/chessPDF_browser.git directorio.pj
```

I have tryed to clone the GIT repository with Netbeans, with the next data:

**repository URL**: frojasg1.com:/home/git/proyectos/chessPDF_browser.git
**user**: git
I used the **cygwin private key file** in Netbeans.

But I have got the next error:

> Incorrect credentials for repository at frojasg1.com:/home/git/proyectos/chessPDF_browser.git

Any ideas about how to be able to clone the repository with Netbeans?

As additional information, the errors logged by netbeans in the **.../var/log/messages.log** file:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:559)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
Caused: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@frojasg1.com:/home/git/proyectos/chessPDF_browser.git: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:159)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.JGitSshSessionFactory.getSession(JGitSshSessionFactory.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:161)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.ListRemoteObjectsCommand.runTransportCommand(ListRemoteObjectsCommand.java:74)
Caused: org.netbeans.libs.git.GitException$AuthorizationException: git@frojasg1.com:/home/git/proyectos/chessPDF_browser.git: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.TransportCommand.handleException(TransportCommand.java:256)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.ListRemoteObjectsCommand.runTransportCommand(ListRemoteObjectsCommand.java:87)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.TransportCommand.run(TransportCommand.java:191)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.GitCommand$1.run(GitCommand.java:80)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.GitCommand$1.run(GitCommand.java:77)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.GitCommand.execute(GitCommand.java:77)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.GitClient.listRemoteBranches(GitClient.java:861)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$35.call(GitClient.java:589)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$35.call(GitClient.java:585)
    at org.openide.util.NetworkSettings.suppressAuthenticationDialog(NetworkSettings.java:140)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker$1$1.call(GitClient.java:885)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker$1.call(GitClient.java:906)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethodIntern(GitClient.java:918)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethod(GitClient.java:851)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethod(GitClient.java:829)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.access$400(GitClient.java:823)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient.listRemoteBranches(GitClient.java:585)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.git.ui.clone.RepositoryStep$RepositoryStepProgressSupport.perform(RepositoryStep.java:325)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitProgressSupport.performIntern(GitProgressSupport.java:114)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitProgressSupport.run(GitProgressSupport.java:107)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1423)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

Comment: I could not solve the issue with Netbeans, but I could avoid it, as said in anhoter thread, by doing the checkout with cygwin:   
`git clone git@frojasg1.com:/home/git/proyectos/chessPDF_browser.git chessPdfBrowser.pj`  and after that, creating a new project from existing sources in Netbeans, with the main folder the one just created (chessPdfBrowser.pj)
Then Netbeans allows you to work with the local git repositoy.
To push to the remote repository, I do it with cygwin: `git push origin master`
To pull from the remote repository, also with cygwin: `git pull origin master`
That's all

Comment: Even better if you use git bash instead of cygwin.
With cygwin sometimes file permission issues appear. That does not happen with git bash (git bash is the terminal application that comes together with git when you install git in your computer).